# Arm assembler invocation in gcc

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I'm trying to invoke asm_uart_string() proc written in asm from C code.
The proc asm_uart_string() takes only one parameter from r0 register and it is address of string to print. I'm trying to pass address of "txt" variable which should be printed:

```
char txt[]="eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee\r\n";
asm("ldr r0, %0" :: "m" (txt));
asm("bl asm_uart_string");
```

however I'm not getting that what I wanted, because objdump returns following code:

```
 7b4:   e59f3058        ldr     r3, [pc, #88]   ; 814 <main+0x3d0>
 7b8:   e5930000        ldr     r0, [r3]
 7bc:   eb0000bb        bl      ab0 <asm_uart_string>
```

I have no much experience in inlining asm in C code and at the moment no idea how to pass address of "txt" to r0 register properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you think it is not what you wanted? I would say it is.

Comment: well it isn't as *clean* as you might want, for that you'd just want the `bl asm_uart_string` to load `r0` as the prerequisite

Comment: @EugeneSh.: I wanted something like this: "add r0, pc, #offset" but as we can see there is r3 register initialized and then dereferenced its contents.

Comment: What is located at `pc + #88`?

Comment: Don't use `ldr r0,%0`, instead use `mov r0, %0`.  You can also use `register char *foo asm ("r0") = &txt[0];` and not do anything in the inline assembler.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: ooops... at pc+#88 is 0xcb0, and at 0xcb0 is my variable "txt".  Seems like you were right and I was wrong. Now I have to check where I've got a bug because it doesn't print this string. Thanks.

Comment: You know, you can simply `asm_uart_string(txt);`, right? If you have `extern void asm_uart_string(char*);` declared (well, `extern` is optional...)